# Enabling Bootstrap multidate with Datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I'm a bit of a newbie to JQuery in general. I'm trying to enable multidate using Bootstrap datepicker. The calendar itself is working i just can't get the multidate function to work and I was wondering if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance !

```
$(function(){
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        multidate: true 
    });
```

Comment: Did my answer worked? if so select it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the options as an object parameter to the **datepicker** function

```
$(function(){
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
             multidate: true 
        });       
});
```

Comment: I tried passing the options as an object parameter as you suggested and the calendar still works but still won't select multiple dates. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Sure for the most part thats all of the code that I have is the modified code you posted and I have it inlined in an html document. I got most of the code from this source http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/. I saw the multidate option in some other documentation here http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/options.html.  I'm  calling bootstrap.css, datepicker.css and boot-strap-datepicker.js from the source that I just listed above, and jQuery 1.11.1 in another .js file.